# Can a ResultSet handle multiple tables?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Say I have a query like this for example:

```
select b.id, b.desc, c.context_desc, d.age 
from 
index a, events b, contexts c, user d
where 
a.id = b.id and a.context_id = c.context_id and a.user_id = d.user_id
order by b.id
```

In Java, can a ResultSet handle multiple tables (assuming the column names are all unique)?

```
int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
String desc = resultSet.getString("desc");
String context_desc = resultSet.getString("context_desc");
int age = resultSet.getInt("age");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

The result set merely contains the columns specified by the `SELECT` clause. It makes absolutely no difference how many tables you have in the `FROM` clause. In your case, your result set will contain columns `id`, `desc`, `context_desc`, and `age`, as you've indicated.

Ultimately, as long as your SQL is legal, meaning that column names are unambiguous, uniquely named, and visible, the result set will contain exactly that which you specify (no more, no less).

This is the [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) documentation, for more information on how it works and what you can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, can a ResultSet handle multiple tables (assuming the column names are all unique)?

Yes this is possible!

If you have 2 columns with the same name, you can give them an alias.